# Return a EF entity with Children as JSON from MVC Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, entity-framework-4

I have an MVC 3 app using EF. On my user login I authenticate the user using ajax and I want to return a list of things that I need them to select. I have ViewModelLogin that has a IEnumerable. I am using AutoMapper to populate the ViewModel from the EF Entity and then return the ViewModel as JSON.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(ViewModelLogin login)
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<ViewModelLogin, User>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Email, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Email))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Password, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Password));

        var user = _userService.GetUser(Mapper.Map<ViewModelLogin, User>(login));

        if (user != null && CreatePasswordHash(login.Password, user.Salt) == user.Password)
        { 
            var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, login.Email, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20), false, "");
            var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket));
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

            Mapper.CreateMap<User, ViewModelLogin>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Things, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Things))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Password, opt => opt.Ignore());
            var returnLogin = Mapper.Map<User, ViewModelLogin>(user);
            returnLogin.Success = true;

            return Json(returnLogin);
        }
        return Json(new ViewModelLogin { Success = false, Message = "Test Message"});
    }
```

When I do this I get an error when the serializer tries to convert the Entity to JSON. The problem is a circular dependency because the collection retains relationship information from EF (In my case a many to many relationship) apart from doing it manually has anybody else solved this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the circular dependency from your view model or you want be able to serialize it as JSON. Also don't call `Mapper.CreateMap<TSource, TDest>` in your controller. This method should be called only once ideally in `Application_Start`.

Comment: There isn't a circular dependency it is a problem with the serializer from what I can gather

Comment: @abarr, the problem is that JavaScriptSerializer cannot serialize circular dependencies, so unless you break this dependency in your object graph you won't be able to JSON serialize it, not to mention that there is nothing in the JSON specification which defines what the syntax for circular dependency would look like.

Comment: http://mytechworld.officeacuity.com/?p=577 this is what I decided to do as I need the many to many relationship between the entities.